# OpenTK 2.0.0 Build From Source Fails

Tags: opentk, build-error

I'm trying to build the OpenTK 2.0.0 source code from the [from the project itself](https://github.com/opentk/opentk), but have encountered this error:[image] I figured perhaps the issue was that the file gl.tm was not being properly copied, so I went to it in the solution explorer and checked "Copy if Newer", but still the problem persists. Has anyone built OpenTK 2.0.0 from source lately; do you know why I am receiving this error?

Edit: I've made ZERO modifications to the source. All I did was download the zip folder, paste it to the desktop, and opened it in visual studio. So this is easily replicatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out. Apparently you have to use the included "build.cmd" located in the project root directory to get a valid build. Everything is working flawlessly now.